# VIM/Python cannot return value to VIM

Tags: python, vim

I'm trying to create a Python plugin for VIM that will detect whether or not the current project is an Android Project. Unfortunately, I cannot get it to return boolean values back to VIM. Calling the plugin from within VIM just outputs nothing. The code below uses the `print` command but I've also tried `vim.command("return {value}")` and setting vim variables from within the script. Any insight?

I have a plugin file with these contents

```
if !has('python')
    echo "Error: Required vim compiled with +python"
    finish
endif


" Get local path for the script, so we can import other files
let s:script_folder_path = escape( expand( '<sfile>:p:h' ), '\' )
let s:python_folder_path = s:script_folder_path . '/../python/'

" Start the python file in the scriptdir
function! s:startPyfile(fileName)
    execute "pyfile " . s:python_folder_path . a:fileName
endfunction
command! Detect call Detect()
function! Detect()
  call s:startPyfile("vim_detect.py")
endfunction
```

which calls vim_detect.py which contains this

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import vim
import os
import sys

# Add current scriptdir to import sources
current_script_dir = vim.eval('s:python_folder_path')
sys.path.append(current_script_dir)

class VimDetect:

    def executeCommand(self):
        if self.isAndroidGradleProject():
            print 1
        else:
            print 0


    def isAndroidGradleProject():
        if(isGradleProject() and isAndroidProject()):
            return True
        else:
            return False


    def isGradleProject():
        if findFileInDirectory("build.gradle"):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def isAndroidProject():
        if findFileInDirectory("AndroidManifest.xml"):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def findFileInDirectory(filename):
        top = os.getcwd()

        matches = 0
        for root, dirnames, files in os.walk(top):
            for file in fnmatch.filter(files, filename):
                matches = matches + 1
        if matches > 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Your python file does nothing but import, and `# Add current scriptdir to import sources` the class was never instantiated.

Comment: You may want to look at [projectionist.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-projectionist) which seems to have similar goals to yours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have commented, your example code (which you should have condensed to a minimal example) isn't actually invoked. The way I've returned a result from Python is by setting a Vim variable, like this:

```
strValue = "just a test"
vim.command("let python_result = '%s'" % str(strValue).replace("'", "''"))
```

For a boolean, just return `0` / `1` as a number, simplifying the logic:

```
vim.command("let python_result = %d" % int(boolValue))
```

Comment: Made these changes. Still didn't work. Set proper variable scoping and it now works! Thanks!

Comment: @Ingo Karkat Great the 'strValue' solution but I noted that it puts an '^M' symbol at every end of line.